# How to set text from YouTube subscriber count JSON file?

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-api, subscriber

I'm developing an app where I want to show total subscribers of a YouTube channel using `JSON`, `AsyncTask`, `TextView`. I don't know how to parse a JSON data. Please help me!

My problem has been solved [HERE](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

The JSON API link [HERE](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCtjgLjaefEi4kcWBl5rpoZg&fields=items/statistics/subscriberCount&key=AIzaSyBU_oWEIULi3-n96vWKETYCMsldYDAlz2M)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCtjgLjaefEi4kcWBl5rpoZg&fields=items/statistics/subscriberCount&key=AIzaSyBU_oWEIULi3-n96vWKETYCMsldYDAlz2M
```

The JSON file itself

[image: JSON file]

JSON.java class

```
public class JSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    String link = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" +
            "UCtjgLjaefEi4kcWBl5rpoZg&fields=items/statistics/subscriberCount&key=AIzaSyBU_oWEIULi3-n96vWKETYCMsldYDAlz2M";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    }
}
```

My main activity

```
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

I desperately need some help, please don't avoid this question!

Comment: Is it my impression or you have included your API key in the url above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google would have yielded you the guidance you needed. There's an [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) in Android Hive. Also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/6143482) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a **LOT** man!! [Android Hive's tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) worked like a charm!